# Read PDF file from S3 Bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, pdf, amazon-s3, pdfbox

I'm writing a java program that reads file from s3 bucket. my code is as below.

```
AmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(myCredentials);
        S3Object xFile = client.getObject("myBucket", "myFile.txt");
        InputStream contents = xFile.getObjectContent();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(contents));
        while (true) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            if (line == null)
                break;

            System.out.println("    " + line);
        }
        System.out.println();
```

And this works fine. i.e. it displays the data correctly.

Similarly I'm trying to read the PDF content from s3 Bucket by making the below change.

```
S3Object xFile = client.getObject("myBucket", "myFile.pdf");
```

When I run this program, it is printing out scrambled text.

In general to read a pdf I use PDfbox, this woks fantastic, but here I want to read it from s3 object. I know that we can read it from s3 file url and passing it onto PDFbox, but that approach won't work for me.

Please let me know how can I do it.

Thanks

Comment: The "scrambled text" is the PDF contents. You can't just print raw PDF data to the screen like that since PDF files aren't plain-text. You will need to use some sort of library that can process PDF files. You seem to be focusing on "read it from an S3 object" but you are already converting the contents of the S3 object to an `InputStream`, and then wrapping that `InputStream` with a `Reader`. You just need to figure out how to read a PDF document from an `InputStream` or `Reader`. I'd be surprised if PDFBox doesn't support that.

Comment: "to read a pdf I use PDfbox, this woks fantastic, but here I want to read it from s3 object" - the code you have posted does not use PDFBox at all, so what did you expect?! And yes, PDF is a binary format. There are many examples here how to convert to image or do text extraction with PDFBox.

Answer (score 1):

PDF is a *binary* format. You will not get plain text out of it without passing it through another program.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? PDF *is* a binary format, and printing it will result in garbage. You're saying PDFbox "won't work" for you, but it's unclear what you're even trying to do.